# nginx proxy_pass is breaking on 302s from the application

Tags: nginx

So I have nginx running as a reverse proxy. It is pointing to a dockerized application.

Part of my configuration works, a call to http://localhost/bstack1 is passed into the application as http://localhost/ (Ignoring the 'bstack1' in the path).

Now comes the problem, the application sends back a 302 to its login page at /login. Instead of http://localhost/bstack1/login the browser shows http://localhost/login which breaks since it no longer matches the location.

I have several applications that will all be running off of different directory paths.

```
# Default
server {
  listen 80 default_server;

  server_name localhost;
  root /var/www/html;

  charset UTF-8;

   location /bstack1/ {
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_buffering off;
    proxy_request_buffering off;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_intercept_errors on;
    proxy_pass http://bstack1_bookstack_1/; # note the trailing slash here, it matters!
  }

  error_page 404 /backend-not-found.html;
  location = /backend-not-found.html {
    allow   all;
  }
  location / {
    return 404;
  }

  access_log off;
  log_not_found off;
  error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log error;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you want the `proxy_redirect` directive in your `location` block, as mentioned here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/26025618

The following would probably be sufficient:

`proxy_redirect default;`

Comment: That does not seem to have worked. 

proxy_redirect default; is an invalid statement since it doesnt have two params
proxy_redirect / /; didnt work either, same output as before

Comment: Not sure why you get an error, however, I think the real issue may be that your container app is returning the hostname "localhost" in the redirect location, rather than "bstack1_bookstack_1". You can confirm that by doing a test curl to your container app. If this is the case, you either need to get your container app returning the correct hostname, or add this to your reverse proxy config:
`proxy_redirect http://localhost/ /bstack2/;`

Comment: Sorry, I meant  `proxy_redirect http://localhost/ /bstack1/;` (accidentally had "bstack2" in the last comment).

Comment: I'm marking this as the correct answer. I ran into a different issue but you solved the first problem. Now files on that login page are trying to load directly from localhost. At this point I may just give up on using the /path/ and try making a sub domain.